# Feature visualization using matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to visualize a data-set which consists of feature and labels. feature shape (200, 2048) and labels are 200.

my problem when I start by implementing plot using matplotlib

the code I started with

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.scatter(features, labels)

plt.show()
```

an error happens when it starts to plot the diagram, related to the size of the X and Y.

The dataset contains 2048 features.I would like to squeeze this 2048 to be one point X and Y in this plot.

my aim is to get a graph where the features are placed and the dots colored with the label name
[image]

Comment: What specifically is your question? What is wrong with your plot? If you are getting an error, what is that error?

Comment: what I want is to visualize dataset draw on the x-axis , y-axis the feature and the labels is the color

Comment: features here are 200 *2048 as a matrix I would like to draw that

Answer (score 1):

You have to define some mapping from 2048 dimensional space to 2 dimensional space, so that final feature is 2 dimensional rather than 2048 dimensional.

Better solution is to use some embeddings like t-SNE:

http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.manifold.TSNE.html

which embeds the 2048 dimensional space to 2 dimensional space, so you can plot your data.

Comment: Ok, basically this data is a features extracted from images . I would like to visual this

Comment: @ahmedosama, you can still use t-SNE to visualize the data.